# Finding the solution of a differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find function $u(x,y,z)$ such that

$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial u }{\partial y}-(x^3y^2+xz)\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=0$$

and $ u|_{x=1}=z$.

My trial

1. $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{-y}=\frac{dz}{-x^3y^2-xz}$$
2. $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{-y}\mspace{10mu},\mspace{10mu}\phi_1(x,y)=xy-C_1=0$$
3. $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dz}{-x^3y^2-xz}\mspace{10mu}???$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dz}{-x^3y^2-xz}$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=-x^2 y^2-z$$
$$z=C_2 e^{-x}-\left(x^2-2 x+2\right) y^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial u }{\partial y}-(x^3y^2+xz)\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=0$$
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{-y}=\frac{dz}{-x^3y^2-xz}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{-y}$
$$xy=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dz}{-x^3y^2-xz}$

$\frac{dz}{dx}+z=-x^2y^2$ is a first order linear ODE where $y$ is a parameter. Solving leads to : $z=c_2e^{-x}+(-x^2+2x-2)y^2$ . The characteristic equation is :
$$e^x z+(x^2-2x+2)y^2e^x=c_2$$

A third characteristic equation comes from $du=0$ :
$$u=c_3$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $\Phi(c_1,c_2,c_3)=0$ where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of three variables.
$$\Phi\big(xy\:,\:e^x z+(x^2-2x+2)y^2e^x\:,\:u\big)=0$$
Or equivalently :
$$u(x,y,z)=F\big(xy\:,\:e^x z+(x^2-2x+2)y^2e^x\big)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables, say $X,Y$ :
$$\boxed{u(x,y,z)=F(X,Y)\quad\begin{cases} X=xy \\ Y=e^x z+(x^2-2x+2)y^2e^x \end{cases}}$$
The function $F$ has to be determined in order to satisfy the condition $u(1,y,z)=z$
$$z=F(X,Y)\quad\begin{cases} X=y \\ Y=e\, z+y^2e \end{cases}\quad\implies\quad Y=e\, F+X^2e$$
$$F(X,Y)=\frac{Y}{e}-X^2$$
Now the function $F$ is known. We put it into the above general solution.

$u(x,y,z)=\frac{e^x z+(x^2-2x+2)y^2e^x }{e}-(xy)^2$

$$u(x,y,z)=e^{x-1} z+(x^2-2x+2)y^2e^{x-1}-x^2y^2$$